# What is the difference between executing in subshells vs using & vs coproc command?

Tags: linux, subshell

I was recently reading about subshells in linux. An example used was sleep 10.

```
(sleep 10)  -  subshell
sleep 10&   - background process
coproc sleep 10
```

It was written that the first command executes in a subshell. The second is the background process without involving a subshell. And the third one was a combination of both.
I had tested using  `ps -ef` and all of these commands show the creation of a subshell. Is there any difference between background process using & and  and subshells? Also coproc seems to do the same thing. I am totally confused. Any light on the topic would be appreciated.

Comment: You tested `(sleep 10)` and `sleep 10&` and saw no difference?

Comment: @muru well ofcourse it frees up the cli for other use when sleep 10&  is used. But other than that it also shows the creation of  a subshell.  Is that the only difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your shell, `sleep` is not a builtin command of the shell, so it has to be executed in a separate process in any case (that would be different in `ksh93` or `mksh` where `sleep` is builtin).

`(sleep 10)` implements a *subshell environment*. The idea is so that any modification to the shell environment (aliases, variables, functions, umask, working directory, redirections...) made inside `(...)` are only affecting that and are lost when `(...)` returns.

In most shells, that's implemented by forking a child process. Not all shells do it that way. `ksh93` instead saves the previous environment settings on a stack and restores them upon exit and doesn't fork in that case.

In many shells, as an optimisation, if the last command in the subshell is an external command (like `sleep` in your case), and there's no `trap` set, the shell doesn't fork a process to run it, but runs it directly in the child process as that process is not going to be needed afterwards anyway.

In the case of the `bash` shell, that only happens if the command is the only command in the subshell (which is also your case here).

`sleep 10&` and `coproc sleep 10` also start a subshell environment, but in those cases, they have to done using a child process, as you have two threads of execution going in parallel. The different between the two is that in the `coproc` case, the subshell has its stdin and stdout connected to two pipes for interaction with the parent.

Like in the `(...)` case, if the subshell is only made of one command, that command is executed directly into the shell's process.

To better see the difference, you'd probably want to run subshells that start more than one command like:

```
{ ps; echo done; } # no subshell
(ps; echo done)
{ ps; echo done; } &
coproc { ps; echo done; }
```